# How to solve error " can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' "?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

i have tried to create indices on my python, when i try to run it, i get error like this :
[image: error]
it is point to ward my root python where i installed it. and i don't know why it show error like this

```
result = [None] * k
```

i have already tried to implement code from https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/507, but it still show the same error.

For somebody who can help me i really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Use integer division `len(x)//5`

Comment: The error message is telling you that `k` isn't an integer. Likely it's because you're using `/` for division instead of `//`.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `random.sample` is the number of selections to make, and it *must* be an integer. You're using a division to create that number; in Python 2 this would be an integer division if both numbers were integers, but in Python 3 it always returns a `float`. The integer division `//` should be used instead:

```
sample_index = random.sample(range(len(x)), len(x) // 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

use integer division `random.sample(range(len(x)), len(x)//5)`